# Error when trying to replace data in a txt file in c#

Tags: c#, replace, storing-data

I am trying to replace data in a `txt` file using `c#`. I tried to use the following code:

```
if (int.TryParse(transaction, out pdt2)) ;
StreamWriter trans = new StreamWriter(transaction);

File.WriteAllText(transaction, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(transaction), pdt2));
```

But the following error appears:

> CS1503   cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

(this referst to pdt2)

I am new to coding, might be a simple solution, but I am stuck at this.

Comment: Well, `pdt2` is an int, `Regex.Replace` expects a string as the replacement, so turn the int into a string, `Regex.Replace(..., pdt2.ToString())`.

Answer (score 1):

`pdt2` is **int** and you must change `pdt2` to **string**.
you can use this

```cs
File.WriteAllText(transaction, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(transaction), pdt2.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe try this too if the above doesnt work:

```
File.WriteAllText(transaction, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(transaction), Convert.ToString(pdt2)));
```